# Retrieve an id in a v-for loop in vue.js

Tags: vue.js, vuejs2, vue-router

I have an array of object call it "articles" that came from an API call and I'm using a v-for loop to display them.

Now, when the user click on one of the article, I would like to retrieve the ID so I can use it to $router.push a query string.

The problem is that, since the articles is an array, I need the right index to retrieve the ID. How can a achieve this ?

Here is sample HTML :

```
        <article  v-for="(article, index) in articles" v-
        on:click="displayArticle" :index="index">
            <h4>{{ article.title }}</h4>
            <p>{{ article.text }}</p>
        </article>
```

Here is a sample vue.js code

```
export default {
data () {
    return {
        articles: []
    }
},
// here I avec a create() that make an API call and push the json in articles.

methods : {
    displayArticle: function() {
    // I don't know ho to retrieve the index 

    // The router part would be something like this
    this.$router.push({ path: '/app/?article_id=', query : {article_id: articleId}}
    }
}
```

I tried using ref but I just get another array.

Thank you for your help

Comment: A key is required when iterating a component. https://vuejs.org/v2/guide/list.html#Components-and-v-for

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`v-on:click="displayArticle(index)"` - just pass the index to your function.

If your ID for each article is not equal to position inside your array (I assume it's not), then you should include an ID of each article into data sent by your server (along with article.title, article.text there should be article.id).

Comment: Better yet, just pass the article.

Comment: @BertEvans absolutely.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot, I passed the article in the function and I retrieved it with

```
this.articles.indexOf(article);
```

Thanks and have a good day

Comment: If you pass in the article, you have it already, you don't have to pull it out of the array.

Comment: Yes, I noticed afterward. I could just use article.id. Thanks